i have a combined pandas dataframe X_train with 22200 samples and 3 features. how can i model this
more info on how data is generated: A signal is passed to a concrete specimen while increasing the frequency of the signal
conductance,susceptance of concrete is measured.The experiment is performed on concrete upto 60 days.The individual day’s concrete strength was obtained by destructive experiment.
how can i model a ml model with this kind of data for predicting a random day concrete strength based on sensor data on that day. sensor data generated for each day is in shape (3700,3), again the strength value for random day is only available we donot have every day concrete strength value.And strength value increases over days
here's the glimpse of dataframe

